# How can I schedule a question to be posted later?

Tags: support, asking-questions, rate-limiting

I just hit the 6 questions in 24 hours limit. How can I queue my question to be posted after 24 hours since my 6th-most-recent question have elapsed?

Comment: This is not supported by the site. Consider looking for a third party utility.

Comment: I don't think this is supported feature at the site but if you start writing your question and close the tab, I think the last thing you started stays as a draft, given that you don't log out of the site and also don't clear your browser cache I suppose

Comment: Why do you even think something like this should exist? Sounds like feature that will be mostly used by spammers, farmers and other site abusers.

Comment: The rate limit exists, so individuals can't ask us a half dozen low-quality and unhelpful questions in less than an hour. What you want isn't possible. You will have to slow down and create high-quality questions, allowing the community time to answer the questions you already asked.

Comment: According to your profile you only asked 4 questions yesterday, which means you've*already* deleted 2 of them. Of the 4, none have a positive score, and 2 have a negative scores. For answers only 2 have received any; 1 you marked as the solution and looks good the other contains screenshots of code and isn't an actual answer. It seems, to me, that you need to spend more time on the questions first before asking a 7th. Especially when it seems that you didn't need to ask 2 of them (as you deleted them).

Comment: One more reason I would be against "scheduling a question", a big cause of *frustration* for Answerers is when Askers don't react (timely) to Comments for clarifications or formatting or correct spelling/grammar/punctuation etc..., and such Questions then tend to get downvoted quicker than if the Asker responds/reacts quickly to Comments...

Answer (score 8):

Type your question and save it as draft. when the time is up, submit it.